# How to replace only certain special characters in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to replace only certain special characters and everything else MUST be kept, so I can't use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and similar codes to keep things and everything else should be replaced.

I tried something like this:

```
$textrim = preg_replace("/(_%:\"`´\[\]\.\(\)\'!\?\.,#‘\<\>-—~\*)/", "", $title);
```

But it doesn't work and I don't find anything on the net, that I could alter for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this.

http://php.net/str_replace

See the second example

```
// Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Comment: Thank's! I accepted this as antwort, because it seems to be the most efficient.

Comment: @Hunnenkoenig In English, we say "answer" for "Antwort" ;)

Comment: Oops... that happens, when you speak 3 languages actively every day :-)

Comment: @Christian Actually, in the Deutsch language, all nouns start with an uppercase letter. "Kein Problem" it should be. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a character class containing the characters you want to replace:

Something like this

```
$out = preg_replace("/[_%:\"`´\[\]()'!?.,#‘<>—~*$-]/", "", $title);
```

should also work.

Comment: Actually I had something like this first and I thought it works, but then I realized, that all my letters were gone and only numbers stay. I don't know why it happened, but I assumed, the "[]" are for KEEPING those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out, after I asked.

```
$textrim = preg_replace('/(_|%|:|"|`|´|\[|\]|\.|\(|\)|\'|!|\?|\.|,|#|‘|\<|\>|-|—|~|\*|\$)/', '', $title);
```