# Convert english double quote to french quote

Tags: php, regex

How can I convert this string in php for example

```
$str = 'Hello world "some text"'
```

to

```
'Hello world «some text»'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We are here to help regarding precise questions, not code for free.

Comment: `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` would be a start...  Give it a shot and then come back when you get stuck

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace only certain special characters in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662128/how-to-replace-only-certain-special-characters-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this :

```
<?php
   $str = 'Hello world "some text"';
   $regex = '/"(.*?)"/';
   $subst = '«$1»';
   $result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $str);
   echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: A `u` modifier probably would make sense for french texts and _please_ remove that closing php tag...